# What is the default value of maxResults in bigquery API call?

Tags: google-bigquery

I am trying to fetch all tables in a particular dataset from bigquery. In api request we can either specify value of `maxResults` or we can ignore it.

1. I wanted to know what is the default value of `maxResults` parameter, that is, if I ignore this parameter in request how many rows would be returned in the response.
2. I also wanted to know that whether the default value of `maxResults` is the same for `list tables`, `list datasets`, and `queries` or it varies.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default maxResults value for any collection.list is 50 except for Tabledata.list    which is 100,000.

The maximum you can set the value for any collection.list is 1,000 except for Tabledata.list which is 100,000.

https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/paging-results